# React Js change static menu to dynamic

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs

i have admin template with sidebar menu that load data hardcode, but i want to use my api to load data sidebar menu.. i don't know how to start it.
[example hardcode menu data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7B2e.png)

[this how menu loaded and merge with others menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwtUo.png)

[this what i've try to retrieve data from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCyAj.png)

but idk, how to include data menu from api to loaded menu

Comment: Please post code, images are not encouraged here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: do not add your code inside images

Comment: Please also note that Java != Javascript and thus the Java tag seems to be wrong here.